# ScrollView in TextView bounces back to Top

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uitextfield

In My ViewController I do have an Textfield and I want to have a scroll function in it because its so long I clicked everything bounces vertically and set the constraints to auto .But when i build it and tried it in the simulator it always bounces back.
I tried everything here in SO but nothing worked for me .
Can anybody help ?

I embed a View in the textfield.

Comment: why have you embedded a view in the text field ? some code on how you're creating the field ? implementing any delegate methods ?

Comment: I´ve done it with out code . Cuz I don't know where do enter the code. And I embed a View cuz i read it here in SO that it would fix it.

Comment: Do you mean that when you have typed something into the text field, then hidden the keyboard it scrolls to the top ?

Comment: No i disabled Edit and selectable cuz its only to view . And if i want to scroll down to the button it immediately scrolls up.

Comment: I don't understand. What's scrolls up ? The view  or the textView ? Do you have a scroll view as your root view ?

Comment: There´s an option in the UITextview in the Abributes Imspector where u can edit the scrollview options. That is what im using . And the textview shall scroll up so i can see the text at the bottom.

Comment: OK I think i get what you mean. The text view is too small for the content ? and you want it to scroll to show the full text ?

Comment: I made a screenshot of it here [link](http://www.suckmypic.net/68286/pic.png)

Comment: Well you either need to make your textview bigger, reduce the amount of text OR let the user scroll it themselves ....

Comment: Ya but how can i let the User scroll it themselves?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, you get it for free with a text view .... Unless you've disabled something.

Comment: I just disabled the editable and selectable.

Comment: What happens if you enable Selectable, that may disable the scrolling...

Comment: Nope it hadn't worked before

Comment: Also Selectable is deprecated now so shouldn't really be using this property anymore.

Comment: What does the text view look like in the app when you run it ?

Comment: like this [link](http://www.suckmypic.net/Eiw8ZSCF.png)

Comment: and you can't scroll it ?

Comment: It bounces back immediately . And if I disable bounces I can't scroll anymore

Comment: bounces back as in bounces back to the top or the natural bounce you get as you scroll over the bounds ? Have you got any code on the view controller where the textview is ?

Comment: I just deleted the textview and done a new after updating xcode and it worked :) Do u maybe know how I can add an Zoom function ?

Comment: on a textview ? I imagine you'd need to override the scrollview